# Regex on URL rewrite module

Tags: asp.net, regex, iis, url-rewriting

I need a help with Regex on URL rewrite module.

I want to apply a rule for the home page.

I tried with ^default.aspx, which is working fine when user access the site with /default.aspx

But normally users are accessing the site with / (www.website.com/) so I am trying to write the reqex and not able to find the correct one.

I tried lot of different combination but nothing worked so far.

```
^(/default.aspx|$|/$)
^(|/|/default.aspx)
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Thanks I removed the ^, but still it is not working. By not working I mean, the rule is applied for other pages also. like www.website.com/aboutus.aspx this page also not got the rule applied. I want the rule only for home page. Thanks

Comment: you should properly specify your rule in the question

Comment: Thanks for the comments. As I mentioned my requirement is to apply the rule for homepage alone.

Comment: you can try `^(www.website.com/)?(/?default.aspx|/)$`

Comment: Thanks. This one is working fine for www.website.com/default.aspx, but it is not working www.website.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following pattern:

```
^(/|default.aspx)?$
```

It will match `/`, `default.aspx` or nothing